# delims attribute of c:forTokens have issues in splitting the content

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I have a JSP page:

```
<c:forTokens items="aaa::::BBB::::[hhhh://abcabc]::::ccc" delims="::::" var="name">
<c:out value="${name}"/><br>
</c:forTokens>
```

I want the output as:

```
aaa
BBB
[hhhh://abcabc]
ccc
```

But what I am getting is:

```
aaa
BBB
[hhhh
//abcabc]
ccc
```

Please help how can i avoid this? I tried this code as well:

```
<c:set var="string1" value="aaa::::BBB::::[hhhh://abcabc]::::ccc"/>
<c:set var="string2" value="${fn:split(string1, '::::')}" />
<c:forEach var="name" items="${string2}">
<c:out value="${name}"/><br>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: You could try using ${fn:split(yourString, '::::')}  instead of using your String as you have it.

Comment: Do you mean like this : <c:forTokens items="${fn:split("aaa::::BBB::::[hhhh://abcabc]::::ccc", '::::')}" delims="::::" var="name"> ? This gives me a compile time error.

Comment: No, you should try using the c:forEach tag. The result of the split is an array. The forTokens wants a String

Comment: No Worked for me. I tried this:  <c:set var="string1" value="aaa::::BBB::::[hhhh://abcabc]::::ccc"/>
 <c:set var="string2" value="${fn:split(string1, '::::')}" />
 <c:forEach var="name" items="${string2}">
  <c:out value="${name}"/><br>
 </c:forEach>     It gives me the same same output as I was getting from my first code

Comment: Sorry, I thought it would work.

Answer (score 0):

The `delims` defines the set of single-character delimiters.  You could write your own custom tag to split the input however you like.

A tutorial on creating JSP tags

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/taglib/quickstart.html

Source of the forTokens tag

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/ForTokensSupport.java?av=f

That tag actually uses java.util.StringTokenizer to do the splitting.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: Why not use fn:split as I commented under question?

Comment: I'm not sure I've never used the fn:split tag.

Comment: fn:split tag also not giving the desired output. I tried this:  <c:set var="string1" value="aaa::::BBB::::[hhhh://abcabc]::::ccc"/>
<c:set var="string2" value="${fn:split(string1, '::::')}" />
<c:forEach var="name" items="${string2}">
<c:out value="${name}"/><br>
</c:forEach>

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get my original idea that I posted in my comments to work. Maybe an expert in regex can get it to work. The challenge is to find the regex pattern that the method Pattern.quote returns. Once that is found it could be used directly in the JSTL. The following JSP is the best that I could do.

```
<%@page import="java.util.regex.Pattern" %>
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%
  String[] myArray = "aaa::::BBB::::[hhhh://abcabc]::::ccc".split(Pattern.quote("::::"));
  pageContext.setAttribute("myArray", myArray);
%>
<c:forEach items='${myArray}' var="name">
    ${name}<br>
</c:forEach>
```